# Android SDK: different activity (view) for settings

Tags: android, android-activity

i build one or two (not very useful) apps, entering stuff etc.

Now my App needs a settings screen. The default template of the sdk brings the settings button, but I want a new screen to open when I push that button. Can you give me any hints?
From my understanding, I need to create a new /res/layout/activity_setup.xml or whatever.

- where else do i need to register that file?
- Howto make it switch

Thanks in advance, guys

Answer (score 1):

Set the button's `onClick` to `startActivity` . I recommend using a [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) for your settings page.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you need to create a new layout (xml file).

Now in your application, you certainly have an Activity class that is called at the beginning of your program. You have to create another class that extends Activity, like

```
class SettingActivity extends Activity{
}
```

and override the same methods as in your main Activity.

for instance

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.setting_layout.xml);
}
```

From your first activity, you can call the new one (SettingActivity) by launchin an intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I recommend you read the android doc, it is really helpful:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

good luck